# Tension on a Graph, Part I: A Wavy String

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

Let's plot a function *f(x) = sin(πx) + 0.5 sin(3πx)* over the domain *[-3,3]*. We can interpret this as a loose string lying on a board. Now let's drive *n* nails into the board at positions *(x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>)* to *(x<sub>n</sub>, y<sub>n</sub>)*, where the *x<sub>i</sub> ∈ (-3,3)* and *y<sub>i</sub> ∈ [-1,1]*. Imagine that there are two eyelets at the end of the string, that is at positions *(-3,0)* and *(3,0)*. We can now take the ends of string and pull the through the eyelets until the string is taut. This will deform our graph into a piecewise linear function.

Some pictures might help. Take 8 nails at *(-2.8, -0.7), (-2.5, -0.9), (-1.2, .2), (-0.5, .8), (0.5, .4), (1.2, -0.9), (1.5, -0.6), (1.8, -0.8)*. The following three plots show the process described above:

[image]

<sup>For larger version: Right-click --> Open in new tab</sup>

And here is an animation of the string tightening if you have some difficulty visualising it:

[image]

### The Challenge

Given a list of "nails" (which is not necessarily sorted), plot those nails and the taut string if it starts from the shape of the above function *f*.

You may write a program or function and take input via STDIN, ARGV or function argument. You can either display the result on the screen or save an image to a file.

If the result is rasterised, it needs to be at least 300 pixels wide and 100 pixels tall. The coordinate range from (-3,-1.1) to (3,1.1) must cover at least 75% of the horizontal and vertical extent of the image. The length scales of *x* and *y* do not have to be the same. You need to show the nails (using at least 3x3 pixels) and the string (at least 1 pixel wide). You may or may not include the axes.

Colours are your choice, but you need at least two distinguishable colours: one for the background and one for the nails and the string (those may have different colours though).

You may assume that all nails are at least 10<sup>-5</sup> units away from *f* (so that you don't need to worry about floating-point inaccuracy).

This is code golf, so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

### More Examples

Here are two more (simpler) examples:

```
{{-2.5, 1}, {-1.5, -1}, {-0.5, 1}, {0.5, -1}, {1.5, 1}, {2.5, -1}}
```

[image]

(The string coincides with the *x*-axis.)

```
{{-2.7, -0.5}, {-2.3, -0.5}, {-1.7, 0.5}, {-1.3, 0.5}, {-0.7, -0.5}, {-0.3, -0.5}, {0.5, 1}, {1.5, -1}, {2.5, 1}}
```

[image]

### Want another Challenge?

[Here is Part II!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38576/8478)

Comment: Can we assume that the nails are sorted from left to right?

Comment: @Ell Ah, good catch. Since I haven't specified it to begin with, no. I'll clarify that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Python <del>+ Pycairo</del>, <del>727</del> <del>708</del> <del>608</del>, + PyLab, 383

```py
from pylab import*
def f(N):
 def P(u,w,N):
    T=lambda v,p:(C(v-u,p-u)>0)==(C(w-v,p-v)>0)==(C(u-w,p-w)>0);M=[(i,n)for i,n in enumerate(N)if T(V([n[0],sin(pi*n[0])+sin(3*pi*n[0])/2]),n)]
    if M:i,n=max(M,key=lambda n:C(n[1]-u,w-u)**2);M=P(u,n,N[:i])+[n]+P(n,w,N[i+1:])
    return M
 V=array;C=cross;a=V([3,0]);plot(*zip(*([-a]+P(-a,a,map(V,sorted(N)))+[a])));N and scatter(*zip(*N));show()
```

**Example**

```
f([(-2.8,-0.7),(-2.5,-0.9),(-1.2,0.2),(-0.5,0.8),(0.5,0.4),(1.2,-0.9),(1.5, -0.6),(1.8, -0.8)])
```

[image: Example 1]

**How it works**

> Suppose we know that the taut string passes through two points *A* and
>  *B* (we can always start with 
>  *A = (-3, 0)* and *B = (3, 0)*.) As we pull the string, it "wants" to take the shortest path possible between
>  *A* and *B*, that is, ideally, the segment *AB*. However, if there are any nails in the area bounded by the function (*sin πx + ...*)
>  and *AB*, then at least one of them must block the string. In
>  particular, the nail(s) farthest away from *AB* within the said area
>  must block the string. Hence, if *C* is this nail, we know that the
>  taut string must pass through *C*, in addition to *A* and *B*. We can
>  now repeat the process for the segments *AC* and *CB*, and continue in
>  this fashion until eventually there are no more intervening nails.
>  [image: Figure 1]
>  
>  
>  This is a binary divide-and-conquer algorithm with a linear scan in
>  each step, so it has a best-case complexity of *O(n log n)* and
>  worst-case complexity of *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

Comment: It errors if the list of points is empty. But other than that mine is obviously hopeless!

Comment: @feersum Good catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## Python + pylab, 576 bytes

#### Algorithm:

> I interpreted the problem as finding the shortest path from *(-3, 0)* to *(3, 0)* such that a vertical line segment connecting a point on the path to a point on *f(x)* never crosses a nail.
>  
>  
>  At each *x* where exists at least one nail, find the least upper bound
>  and greatest lower bound given by the nails at that *x*. Consider the
>  points given by these bounds plus the starting and ending points to be
>  the vertices on a graph. Add an edge with weight given by the
>  Euclidean distance between two vertices iff the line segment between
>  them falls within the upper and lower bounds for each intervening x
>  coordinate. Find the shortest path on this graph.

#### Example with 27 random points:

```
(-0.367534, -0.722751), (-0.710649, -0.701412), (1.593101, -0.484983), (1.771199, 0.681435), (-1.878764, -0.491436), (-0.061414, 0.628570), (-0.326483, -0.512950), (0.877878, 0.858527), (1.256189, -0.300032), (1.528120, -0.606809), (-1.343850, -0.497832), (1.078216, 0.232089), (0.930588, -0.053422), (-2.024330, -0.296681), (-2.286014, 0.661657), (-0.009816, 0.170528), (2.758464, 0.099447), (-0.957686, 0.834387), (0.511607, -0.428322), (-1.657128, 0.514400), (1.507602, 0.507458), (-1.469429, -0.239108), (0.035742, 0.135643), (1.194460, -0.848291), (2.345420, -0.892100), (2.755749, 0.061595), (0.283293, 0.558334),
```

[image: lame example]

**Golfed**

What appears as several spaces of indentation in the `for j in R(i&~1)` loop should actually be a tab.

```
from pylab import*
P=((3,0),(-3,0))+input()
X=sorted(set(zip(*P)[0]))
l=len(X)*2
if l>4:scatter(*zip(*P[2:]))
f=lambda x:sin(pi*x)+sin(3*pi*x)/2
B=[[max([-9]+[p[1]for p in P if x==p[0]and p[1]<f(x)]),min([9]+[p[1]for p in P if x==p[0]and p[1]>f(x)])]for x in X]
b=zeros(l);b[2:]=inf
v=list(b)
R=range
for i in R(l):
 for j in R(i&~1):
    A=B[j/2][j&1];D,d=B[i/2][i&1]-A,X[i/2]-X[j/2];K=1;c=b[j]+norm((d,D))
    for k in R(j/2+1,i/2):C=A+D/d*(X[k]-X[j/2]);K&=C<B[k][1];K&=C>B[k][0]
    if(c<b[i])&K:b[i]=c;v[i]=j,(X[j/2],A)
l-=2
s=P[:1]
while l/2:l,p=v[l];s+=(p,)
plot(*zip(*s))
show()
```

**Ungolfed**

```
from pylab import*
P = input()
Xn,Yn = zip(*P)
X = set(Xn+(3,-3))
f = lambda x:sin(pi*x)+sin(3*pi*x)/2
ylb = {x: max([-9]+[p[1] for p in P if p[0] == x and p[1] < f(x)]) for x in X}
yub = {x: min([9]+[p[1] for p in P if p[0] == x and p[1] > f(x)]) for x in X}
ylb[-3] = yub[3] = ylb[3] = 0
X = sorted(X)
l = len(X)
best = zeros((l,2))
best[1:] = inf
prev = [ [0,0] for i in range(l) ]
for i in range(l): # calculate min path to X[i] lb or ub
  for ib in 0,1:
    for j in range(i): # point to come from
      for jb in 0,1:
          Y2, Y1 = (ylb, yub)[ib][X[i]], (ylb, yub)[jb][X[j]]
          dy,dx = Y2 - Y1, X[i] - X[j]
          if all([Y1 + dy/dx*(x - X[j]) < yub[x] and Y1 + dy/dx*(x - X[j]) > ylb[x] for x in X[j+1:i]]):
             c = best[j][jb] + (dy**2+dx**2)**.5
             if c < best[i][ib]:
                 best[i][ib] = c
                 prev[i][ib] = j, jb, (X[j], Y1)
j, jb = l-1,0
pts = [(3,0)]
while j:
    j, jb, p = prev[j][jb]
    pts += [p]
plot(*zip(*pts))
scatter(Xn,Yn)
show()
```

Comment: PyLab was definitely a smarter choice :)